# How to pass special parameters in a function in Ruby Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver Ruby to create a function in order to wait for an element displayed within a Time that I set in this function

My function will have two parameters (one **Optional** parameter & one parameter is **locator name of an object**)

So, I have my function with two parameters like below:

```
def wait_for_element_displayed(locator, options={})
    if options[:time]
       settime = options[:time]
    else
       settime= 60
    end
    @driver.find_element(locator).click
end
```

So, I will call this function like: **wait_for_element_displayed(:id=>"unique1", :time => "20")**

However, I got the error when trying to calling this function with this way, the error is: "TypeError: can't convert String into an exact number".

Anybody please help me how to pass two parameters like my scenario to a function? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

You can use `hash#fetch` to set a default value if the key you are looking up is not present:

```
time = options.fetch(:time) { 60 }
```

Ruby will have a hard time parsing your input when both arguments are hashes and you don't differentiate between them. Also, your error makes me think you should provide 20 as an integer instead of a string. Try calling the method like this:

```
wait_for_element_displayed({:id => "unique1"}, { :time => 20 })
```

Lastly, I don't know much about Selenium, so maybe someone can fill me in on the last point. Is setting a `settime` variable sufficient to configure timeouts?

Comment: calling the function with this one resolved my problem: wait_for_element_displayed({:id => "unique1"}, { :time => 20 }). Thanks so much for your great help.